# iOS 14 local network privacy permission request not triggered

Tags: xamarin.ios, ios14, privacy, ios15, local-network

*October 2021 Update*

We have updated our applications to be built gainst **ios SDK 14.5** and have made the same tests on ios 15 devices. The problem is still there. The second application does not trigger the local network permission prompt

---

I have two in house **xamarin.ios** applications build against **ios SDK 11.2**
When i try to install the first application on a device running on ios 14 i see the prompt message asking the user for permission to access the **Local Network**.
However, if i grant access and try to install the second application it never asks again with a consequence the second application to fail in all network calls

Comment: Open the system setting to check if the second app has the permission of local network . You could create a new bundle id for the second application in develop account and try again .

Comment: Unfortunately the second app does not have an entry at the local network settings list.

Comment: Create a new bundle id for the second application  and try again .

Comment: The two applications have different app ids. I cannot change the id to the second app,, since it is already installed on many client devices

Comment: The alert will only appear once when it installing on the device .

Comment: the problem is that the alert doesn't show for the second application

Comment: So you could create a new project to check again if the issue still exists .

Comment: I have already done that thank you, and the issue exists

Comment: Looks like this issue has come back in iOS 15 :(

Answer (score 1):

From iOS 14.2, the app is correctly triggering the network privacy alert after an upgrade , full deletion and reinstall. Recommend you to upgrade to 14.2 check if it is works now.

Comment: Confirmed, update iOS and reinstall the app solve the issue. Tks!

Comment: Unfortunately , we are still having the same problem with IOS 15